# Django e-commerce wishlists in dropdown menu on product page of currently logged in user

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

What I'm trying to achieve is give the currently logged in user the ability to add a product to a specific wishlist that the user has created earlier. To do this I want there to be a dropdown menu button with a list of all the current wishlists which the user has with a checkbox.

I have tried 2 ways to achieve this but none works as desired. What is the proper way to do this?

models.py

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)

    wishlist_cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/WISHLIST_COVER_IMAGES/', null=True,blank=True)

    description = RichTextField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)

    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True,blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False ,null=True,blank=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ecommerce:wishlist', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

With the below implementation I tried to do the user filtering with the traditional way by using "request.user" and got "request not defined" error.

forms.py

```
class AddToWishlistForm(forms.ModelForm):

    wishlists = CustomWLMenu(queryset=Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['wishlists']
```

After looking around for a solution I came across the below method which retrieves all the wishlists rather than the currently logged in user like so:

[image]

forms.py

```
class CustomWLMenu(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, user):

        return "%s" % user      

class AddToWishlistForm(forms.ModelForm):

    wishlists = CustomWLMenu(queryset=Wishlist.objects.filter(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['wishlists']
```

Comment: Share the models currently made, as well as the view and the full traceback.

Comment: Can you also add the form/queryset you are trying to use?

Comment: @willeM_ Van Onsem
updated the post

Comment: You can try ```return "%s" % user if user.is_authenticated else None```.  You can also try blank string instead of None as I am not sure what will be the behaviour in case else is executed.

Comment: @Rishab Mamgai tried not working